# Retrieve two Value from same collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I Have this collection

```
{    
    "name" : "users",
    "value" : [ 
        "foo", 
        "bar", 
        "buz"
    ]
}

{
    "name" : "languages",
    "value" : [ 
        "fr", 
        "en", 
        "jp"
    ]
}
```

and I want to retrieve the array of both Value and return something like this

```
{
valueUser['foo','bar','buz'],
languages['fr','en','jp'],
}
```

I have to do Two Query ? or I Can do a single query?

Answer (score 1):

More use of aggregate, but this is pretty involved. So best to run each stage to see what is happening.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "valueUser": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$name", "users" ] },
                "$value",
                 [false]        
        ]},
        "languages": { "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$name", "languages" ] },
                "$value",
                 [false]
        ]}
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$valueUser" },
    { "$unwind": "$languages" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "valueUser": { "$push": "$valueUser" },
        "languages": { "$push": "$languages" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$valueUser" },
    { "$match": { "valueUser": { "$ne": false } } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$languages",
        "valueUser": { "$push": "$valueUser" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$_id" },
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": false } } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$valueUser",
        "languages": { "$push": "$_id" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "valueUser": "$_id",
        "languages": 1
    }}
])
```

So that gives you the basic concept of **how** to "split-up" fields from documents.

Possibly here you need to consider you use case for what you actually want to do as the process is very involved.

Comment: I did try this solution, but I have this error `Error: Line 13: Unexpected token }`. I don't understand where is this error

Comment: @monkeyUser Seems that what was there was posted by accident. Anyhow I have a working sample in here now. But consider what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get result like you want in your example. But you can get data in one query like
this:

```
db.collection.find({}, {name : true, value : true, _id : false})
```

Result will be:

```
[
    { "name" : "users", "value" : [ "foo", "bar", "buz" ] }
    { "name" : "languages", "value" : [ "fr", "en", "jp" ] }
]
```

Think this will be helpful for you.

Comment: Have a look at the "other" answer. Of course you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the aggregation framework to include values from all documents:

```
db.col.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$name", values: { $addToSet: "$value" } } },
  { $project : { _id: 0, name: "$_id", values: 1 }}
])
```

For a collection like this:

```
{"name" : "users", "value" : ["foo", "bar", "buz"]},
{"name" : "users", "value" : ["bif", "bar", "nerf"]},
{"name" : "languages", "value" : [ "fr", "en", "jp"]}
```

Results would be this.

```
[
    { "name" : "users", "value" : [ "foo", "bar", "buz", "bif", "nerf" ] }
    { "name" : "languages", "value" : [ "fr", "en", "jp" ] }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but in Javascript (node.js) for retrieve languages value i have to do a cycle and check if languages or users.. I'd like have two different results, sorry for my english and thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data corresponding to user and languages by using

```
 db.collection.find({},{_id:0})
```

result will be

`[
    { "name" : "users", "value" : [ "foo", "bar", "buz" ] }
    { "name" : "languages", "value" : [ "fr", "en", "jp" ] }
]`

if you want to retrieve the way you have mentioned in the question then you need to insert this way

```
db.collection.insert({"name":"users", "valueUser":["foo","bar","buz"]}
db.collection.insert({"name":"languages", "valueLanguages":["fr","en","jp"]})
```

then retreive the data like this

```
db.collection.find({},{_id:0,name:0})
```

the result will be

```
{ "valueUser" : [ "foo" , "bar" , "buzz" ] }
{ "valueLanguages" : [ "fr" , "en" , "jp" ] }
```